# Il fait froid AU / DANS LE / SUR LE nord?

Tags: prépositions, indications-de-lieu

Je suis sûr (ou presque) d'avoir entendu toutes ses variations:

- au nord
- dans le nord
- sur le nord ([la météo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E01GK3ZcGWU)  00:47)

Ce que je veux dire en anglais serait "It's cold in the north".

Ma question est donc, les options ci-dessus sont-elles toutes possibles dans tous les contextes? Ou est-ce que je devrais éviter/favoriser certaines dans certains contextes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In French, when talking about cardinal directions, prepositions may change the meaning of the phrase:

> Dans le nord/sud/ouest/est de la région/du pays

points to regions that are part of the geographical zone the speaker is talking about

> Au nord/sud/à l'est/ouest de la région du pays

points to regions that are OUTSIDE of the zone

> Ex: Marseille est dans le sud de la France, mais la Belgique est au nord de la France.

"Sur" used with a cardinal direction is less common, but it the context of weather, it can be used with some verbs or phrases where the weather condition is seen as "falling down" on a region. You will say

> il pleut sur le nord/sud/etc, le soleil brille sur le sud/nord/etc

just like you would say

> il pleut sur la France/sur l'Alsace, le soleil brille sur la France/l'Alsace

"Il fait froid sur le nord/ouest/etc" would be understood but sounds awkward, just as "il fait froid sur la France/sur l'Alsace". But note that you would say "une vague de froid s'abat sur le nord/la France/etc", because there is still still this sense that something is falling down on the region.

Note that *le Nord* (mind the capital letter) is also a the name of a *departement* in France, so the French weatherman/woman could say "il pleut sur le Nord" and refer then to this department.

Comment: Je suis d'accord pour la différence de sens entre *au* et *dans le* mais dans l'usage, on rencontre de plus en plus souvent le premier pour le second. C'est un peu comme si la référence devenait le centre, *au nord* signifie alors *au nord du centre* ou *au nord du reste du pays, de la région*. L'hymne officieux de (l'ex) Nord-Pas-de Calais dit bien ***Au nord**, c'était les corons, la terre, c'était le charbon...*

Comment: Exact: en particulier pour les bulletins météo des chaînes nationales françaises bien jacobines, Paris est le point de référence, et donc "au nord" sans plus de détail veut alors dire " tout ce qui est au nord de Paris". Et paradoxalement, Bachelet n'a en fait jamais vécu dans les régions minières du Nord, mais à Paris et à Calais, donc "Au nord" est peut-être aussi vu depuis Paris où il a vécu dans son enfance.

Comment: C'est plutôt la moitié nord et la moitié sud de la France qui sont souvent  prises comme référence lors des bulletins météo français et Paris est situé dans ce cas « au nord ». À Marseille, en revanche, le nord commence à Montélimar... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

"It's cold in the north". In French "il fait froid dans le nord" is the best variation.
You could say "il fait froid au nord"

But "sur le nord" sounds awkward.
J'ai écouté [la vidéo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E01GK3ZcGWU) sans entendre l'expression "sur le nord". May you point in the timeline.

Comment: Il le dit plusieurs fois. e.g. 00:47 (mais il dit "ouest, etc, pas nord")

Comment: It's common in meteorology to speak of weather that way, e.g in the UK a forecaster may say "an area of low pressure over the North of England" (as opposed to "in" the North).